# How do I apply a border on a picture from another picture

Tags: images, png

I want to add the border on this picture:

[image: http://aurorasvoice.org/uploads/quotes/martin-luther-king-jr.jpg]

to this picture:

[image: http://aurorasvoice.org/uploads/quotes/daniel_webster.png]

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing a 1-pixel `#CBA133` border around the first picture. You can add this to the 2nd one using Photoshop or Pixlr.com if you don't have it.

Loading your image:

1. Go to http://pixlr.com/editor/.
2. Click **Open image from computer**, select your file and click **Open**. You could also click **Open image from URL** then paste `https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sS9O.png` into the field.

Adding the border:

1. Go to **Layer** > **Layer Styles**
2. Check and click **Inner Glow**.
3. Set the **Opacity** to `100`, **Hardness** to `10` and **Size** to `2`. Like so:

   [image: Image 1]
4. Click the color box and type `CBA133` into the field beside **#**, like so:

   [image: Image 2]
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save.

   [image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1):

### You can use a image editing program like [Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/) or [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

---

Alternatively you can do this in MS paint following these simple steps:

**Step1:**
Open the first image in MS Paint.
Take the RGB value of the color of the border using the *Pick Color* tool.
[image: image border clolor]
(R,G,B)
(206,154,36)

**Step2:**
Open the second image in MS Paint and expand the border.
[image: image resized too include border]

**Step3:**
Center the image using *Select* tool and select the color from *Colors>Edit Colors...>Define Custom Colors>>*
Add the RGB value here to get the color we want.
Then using the *Fill With Color* tool fill the color in the border.
You may want to use the *Magnifier* tool while centering the image and while filling the color.

---

And here is your final result.
[image: final image]